# The pk-client-error-quark message appears when trying to switch to Broadcom Wi-Fi driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, wifi-hardware-switch

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 but the laptop could not access the wireless LAN. In Software & Updates I enabled the Broadcom proprietary Wi-Fi driver but got the pk-client-error-quark message. So now I cannot access the upgrade/package/driver/whatever from the Internet because Ubuntu cannot access the Internet.

Is there any way of downloading the fix on another (Windows) laptop, saving the fix to an USB stick, and then installing the fix on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop? Or some other solution? Why doesn't the Ubuntu open-source wifi/network driver work?